# Create a temporary table from a subquery in sql server causing error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, subquery, temp-tables

I have something like this

```
 if object_id('tempdb.#TempHourlyTable') is not null
drop table #TempHourlyTable

 select * into #TempHourlyTable
 from (
         select top 10 * from customers
      )
```

I get an error like this:

> Incorrect syntax near ')'.

My first attempt with temporary tables. So what is the mistake here?

EDIT:
Drop and recreate if temporary table exists. Getting error

> Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 55
>       There is already an object named '#TempHourlyTable' in the database.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to alias your derived table (subquery), like:

```
select * into #TEmpTable
 from (
         select top 10 * from customers
      ) as [SomeAlias]
```

You can also:

```
select top 10 * 
into #temp
from customers
```

Comment: Thanks. I got through your approach. Although i have a new question. I edited my current question. Can you take a look at it?Thanks

Comment: Need another dot:  object_id('tempdb..#TempHourlyTable')

Comment: for added info ...  it doesn't work without the alias even though alias not necessarily referenced in the select-into. (I tried leaving it out in the interests of streamlined coding). I'll know better next time!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
insert into #TEmpTable 
select top (10) * from customers
```

what are you looking to do with the temp. table?

i find using CTEs much more convenient

[CTEs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. I have a new question. I edited my current question. Can you take a look at it?